# SwaggerUI one or more yaml / json files for API(s)?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

Currently, we generated a yaml for each of our web service endpoints:

```
res1.yaml -> host/res1
res2.yaml -> host/res2
...
```

However, we would like to display all APIs with SwaggerUI.
In SwaggerUI, there is one reference to one yaml file.

Can I use SwaggerUI with multiple yaml files or do I need to refactor my yaml documents into one?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Swagger 2.0 specification:

> The Swagger representation of the API is made of a single file. However, parts of the definitions can be split into separate files, at the discretion of the user. This is applicable for $ref fields in the specification as follows from the JSON Schema definitions.

This means your documents should be a single file, but it allows for external files wherever $ref is used. So you cannot split a single service into several files and combine them as one, but you can specify operations for specific paths externally using the $ref property.

Here is a very good article about how you can split your Swagger documents: http://azimi.me/2015/07/16/split-swagger-into-smaller-files.html

Comment: so what does it mean for SwaggerUI ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. swagger-ui can only show one single main swagger document. However, this document can reference other YAML docs for things like response def, parameter def...

Comment: Hi, the references can only point to defintions and schemas but not to other api descriptions (operations, endpoints) ?

Comment: You can share API Operations, in addition to parameters, responses, etc. Here's an example of how you can reference operations: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/guidelines/REUSE.md#operations